# Tell Spring not to invoke shutdown on beans of a specific type

Tags: java, spring, destructor, lifecycle, application-shutdown

On application close, each singleton bean is destroyed by DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons().
If the bean has a public void no-arg method called shutdown, then it will be invoked.
I have some 3rd party beans, all of which implement a certain interface, let's call it DoNotDestroy, that I do not want Spring to destroy.

I can specify a blank string destroy method on each bean, like so:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
public MyBean myBean() {
    return new MyBean();
}
```

However, I would prefer to somehow configure Spring to not destroy any beans that implement DoNotDestroy. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than blanking out the destroy method in each @Bean method, I can implement a BeanFactoryPostProcessor to do the same thing:

```
@Component
public class DoNotDestroyPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DoNotDestroyPostProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        String[] doNotDestroys = beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DoNotDestroy.class);
        for (String doNotDestroy : doNotDestroys) {
            BeanDefinition bean = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(doNotDestroy);
            log.info("Don't destroy bean {} {}", bean.getFactoryMethodName(), bean.getDestroyMethodName());
            bean.setDestroyMethodName("");
        }
    }
}
```

This avoids the problem of someone adding a bean and forgetting to blank out the destroy method.